# Sum multiple records using if condition

Tags: database, ms-access-2010

I am trying to sum all the records that are the same and only list them once (see **Project list** image below). 
I've used the `Sum` function but I'm not quite sure how to write the `If` condition. 
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Vick that is a simple group by statement like:  `select Project, ActivityType, Company, Sum(Hours) as Hours from ProjectList group by Project, ActivityType, Company`

Comment: Thank you. I've actually created a query and added the summary options to sum the hours and it looks good in my report but once i added new records it doesn't work. So it worked only for old data :(